# DisplayCond equation between two values

Tags: typo3, backend

I am trying to figure it out how can I display field in TCA when two values of other fields are same?

My configuration is that I have two fields `new` and `old` and one field `second`. I would like to reach that field `second` is displayed when `new` and `old` are same or `new=1` (this is working).

```
$fields[] = array(
    'new' => array(
        'label' => "New ID",
        'exclude'   => 1,
        'config'    => array(
            'type' => 'input'
        )
    ),
);

$fields[] = array(
    'old' => array(
        'label' => "old ID",
        'exclude'   => 1,
        'config'    => array(
            'type' => 'input'
        )
    ),
);

$fields[] = array(
    'second' => array(
        'exclude'   => 1,
        'displayCond' => array(
            'OR' => array(
                'FIELD:new:=:1',
                'FIELD:new:=FIELD:old'
            )
        ),
        'config'    => array(
            'type' => 'input',
            'size' => '255',
        )
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax ''FIELD:new:=FIELD:old' is not allowed by the display condition parser (which i rewrote in core v8). Thus, you can not compare the values of two different fields directly, and you are not able to solve your issue on a display condition level.

You may solve your issue by adding a new data provider (probably after the EvaluateDisplayConditionDataProvider) that removes your column in your special case, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormEngine/Index.html for more docs.